# Docker and Java - Read and Write from current terminal window

Tags: java, docker

Problem: I have a java program that reads and writes from terminal. I want to make a docker image that when it runs writes and reads from my current terminal window. I have searched in other posts but all solutions found don't seem to work.
Thank You.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

RUN mkdir /RMIClient
WORKDIR /RMIClient
COPY . .

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV RMISERVER_PORT 3333

CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac Main.java && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java Main"]
```

Comment: Could you explain which problem you are facing? Btw. your CMD instruction is wrong.

Comment: The problem is when running the images I need it to read and write from the current terminal window. For example, if I have a print or something like that. Another thing, why is my CMD instruction wrong? Maybe that's the problem. Thank You.

Comment: I meant, what exactly happens when you run your image? As for the CMD, you probably meant `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac Main.java && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java Main"]`

Comment: And why don't you do the compilation when you create the image instead of when you start the container?

Comment: I didn't think of that. So now I changed it to compile when the image is created. But what I really need to write and read from my current terminal window when I run sudo docker run <Image Name>. For example, If I have this code  

System.out.println("hello");  

it should print hello to my terminal.

Comment: use `sudo docker run -it <image name>`

Comment: Ok, it worked. Thank you.